# Difference between glframebuffertexture and glbindtexture

Tags: c#, opengl

What are the exact usage differences between the two functions **glframebuffertexture** and **glbindtexture** in OpenGL.

To put into context, I am using OpenTK to write a custom lightweight UI using OpenGL for an embeded machine, which uses lots of framebuffers and respective textures for different components in the UI. Internally the framebuffers are tracked using a stack as buffer contents can be drawn into the "parent" buffer (or if no parent the screen space).

Im having a hard time trying to get the calls in the right order and im wondering if i have got confused with when I need to bind a texture to a frame buffer and when I need to assign a texture to a frame buffer.

I have read the docs on these functions but they dont really explain the relationships between these functions in their context with the frame buffer.

Im basically ending up with nothing being rendered back to screen.

For example if im rendering text with SharpFont (FreeType binding lib) I have one framebuffer for the whole rendered string and one framebuffer to render each character to.

This is the general sequence of how I believe the calls are to be made in this example

1. Starting at FB0 (Screen space),
2. Create FB 1,
3. Setup FB 1 (bind to FB 1) with TX 1 (Create then Bind to then attach),
4. Bind back to FB0,
5. Bind to FB1 (to start rendering to),
6. Create FB2,
7. Setup FB 2 (bind to FB 2) with TX 2 (Create then Bind to then attach), (including rendered character pixel data),
8. Bind Back to FB1,
9. Bind to TX2
10. Render TX2 (supposedly) with quad
11. Repeat at 7 for next character until end
12. Bind Back to FB0
13. Render TX1 (supposedly) with quad.

---

FrameBuffer (UI Object)

```
    public class OGLFrameBuffer : IFrameBuffer {

    private int frameBufferId = -1;
    private int frameBufferTexture = -1;

    private IDrawer ctx;

    public OGLFrameBuffer(IDrawer dCtx) { ctx = dCtx; }

    public void SetupFrameBuffer(float width, float height) {

        //Generate Frame Buffer if not exists;
        if (frameBufferId == -1) {
            frameBufferId = GL.GenFramebuffer();
        }

        //set current frame buffer
        ctx.PushUseFrameBuffer(this, new Size((int)Math.Ceiling(width), (int)Math.Ceiling(height)));

        if (frameBufferTexture != -1)
            GL.DeleteTexture(frameBufferTexture);

        //Generate Texture with buffer size;
        frameBufferTexture = GL.GenTexture();
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, frameBufferTexture);

        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);

        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, (int)Math.Ceiling(width), (int)Math.Ceiling(height), 0, PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, IntPtr.Zero);

        GL.FramebufferTexture(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0, frameBufferTexture, 0);

        //return to previous buffer
        ctx.PopFrameBuffer();

    }

    public void SetupFrameBuffer(float width, float height, byte[] data, VIPixelFormat pixelFormat) {

        PixelFormat oglPixFmt;

        switch (pixelFormat) {
            case VIPixelFormat.VIPF_RGBA:
                oglPixFmt = PixelFormat.Bgra;
                break;
            case VIPixelFormat.VIPF_GREYSCALE:
                oglPixFmt = PixelFormat.Red;
                break;
            case VIPixelFormat.VIPF_RGB:
            default:
                oglPixFmt = PixelFormat.Bgr;
                break;
        }

        //Generate Frame Buffer if not exists;
        if (frameBufferId == -1) {
            frameBufferId = GL.GenFramebuffer();               
        }

        //set current frame buffer
        ctx.PushUseFrameBuffer(this, new Size((int)Math.Ceiling(width), (int)Math.Ceiling(height)));

        if (frameBufferTexture != -1)
            GL.DeleteTexture(frameBufferTexture);

        //Generate Texture with buffer size;
        frameBufferTexture = GL.GenTexture();
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, frameBufferTexture);

        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);

        if (pixelFormat == VIPixelFormat.VIPF_GREYSCALE) {
            //GL.ClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
            //GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        }

        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, (int)Math.Ceiling(width), (int)Math.Ceiling(height), 0, oglPixFmt, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data);

        GL.FramebufferTexture(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0, frameBufferTexture, 0);

        //return to previous buffer
        ctx.PopFrameBuffer();

    }

    public int GetFrameBufferId() {
        return frameBufferId;
    }

    public int GetFrameBufferTexture() {
        return frameBufferTexture;
    }
}
```

Relevant Context Calls:

```
        public void PushUseFrameBuffer(IFrameBuffer buf, Size bufferDims) {
        frameBufferStack.Push(buf);
        OGLFrameBuffer frameBuf = (OGLFrameBuffer)buf;
        GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, frameBuf.GetFrameBufferId());
        ctxbounds = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), bufferDims);
    }

    public void PopFrameBuffer() {
        frameBufferStack.Pop();

        if (frameBufferStack.Count != 0) {
            OGLFrameBuffer frameBuf = (OGLFrameBuffer)frameBufferStack.Peek();
            GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, frameBuf.GetFrameBufferId());
        }
        else {
            GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0);
        }

        ctxbounds = windowbounds;
    }

public void DrawBuffer(IFrameBuffer buff, RectangleF textureBounds, Size parentBounds) {

        OGLFrameBuffer toDrawFb = (OGLFrameBuffer)buff;

        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, toDrawFb.GetFrameBufferTexture());

        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);

        GL.TexCoord2(0.0f, 1.0f); GL.Vertex2((textureBounds.X * scale)                         / parentBounds.Width , (textureBounds.Y * scale)                          / parentBounds.Height);
        GL.TexCoord2(1.0f, 1.0f); GL.Vertex2(((textureBounds.X + textureBounds.Width) * scale) / parentBounds.Width , (textureBounds.Y * scale)                          / parentBounds.Height);
        GL.TexCoord2(1.0f, 0.0f); GL.Vertex2(((textureBounds.X + textureBounds.Width) * scale) / parentBounds.Width , ((textureBounds.Y + textureBounds.Height) * scale) / parentBounds.Height);
        GL.TexCoord2(0.0f, 0.0f); GL.Vertex2((textureBounds.X * scale)                         / parentBounds.Width , ((textureBounds.Y + textureBounds.Height) * scale) / parentBounds.Height);

        GL.End();

        OGLFrameBuffer curFb = (OGLFrameBuffer)GetCurrentFrameBuffer();

        if (curFb != null) {
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, curFb.GetFrameBufferTexture());
        }
        else {
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);
        }

        SetColour(1, 1, 1, 1f);
        DrawRectangle(textureBounds);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

glFrameBufferTexture associate the texture to the framebuffer as a render target.

It means that when you will issue a drawcall, this texture will be write by the output of your fragment shader (with blending if enabled).

GlBindTexture tells OpenGL you want to read this texture (via a sampler2D for example)

To be simple : glFrameBufferTexture allows you to render (or write) into this texture instead of your own screen, glBindTexture allows you to read data inside the texture (it could be a texture you wrote thanks a framebuffer, or a texture you wrote when loading an image).

EDIT : More generally, bind an object in OpenGL tells OpenGL that it will use this object for all subsequent operation.

When you want to do a glTexParameter, you must need to bind the texture you are working on prior. Or use DSA with; glTextureParameter/

For buffers and other objects it is the same

Comment: after looking at tutorials on how to set up a frame buffer with a texture, they bind to the texture and then call glTexParameter. Is calling glBindTexture really needed in this case then? Since i am not actually reading the texture im effectively writing changes to it.

Comment: yes ok technically binding means to use (read) or change settings (not make draw calls). So if I my frame buffer is currently bound to another texture and i bind back to the buffer at 0, does this imply that the frame buffer no longer refers to any texture for useage, or is texture name 0 a default texture assigned at opengl init time?

Comment: GlBind To 0 means you dont want To have a object bound anymore.